# what's better : create new object every time OR store it in session?

Tags: asp.net, performance, session, object, pagespeed

Lets take an example of a table adapter (typed data-sets)

I am storing data-set in session. but I don't know what is better for table adapters.

In general, will creating object hit performance badly when compared to storing and getting from session ?

Comment: I don't do asp but from years of programming its like this: It depends on how you use the data. Always cache data if you are not done with it, and release the resource when it is not immediately needed. The last rule must be subject to your workload and resources to perform any operation of this type "effectively".

Comment: If you'll take me under advisement, you'll avoid a lot of bad code and always write data operations that are task oriented. This is how the cpu operates at the core level. To a high level language, resources seem limitless but from the assembler perspective, waiting for state based on assumption is a bad idea, meaning code we shouldn't have had to run or run again. If you speak the language, you can win the game, and that is the task at hand. Small simple tasks.

`load`, `get`, `set`, `save` you then build on that what your application needs not what somebody else thought was your best option.

Comment: Computers were invented to do two things really well. Input, and output. It is up to the engineer to decide what happens between those two points. And you can add that up on your Abacus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two alternatives uses different resources.

Creating a new instance of an object uses time. Storing the instance in the session uses memory.

If you create a new instance each time you need one, it will only take up memory for the short while that you are using it. If you store it in the session, it will take up memory all the time, and if you don't remove it from the session it will even take up memory for a while after the user has left.

If you were thinking of keeping the table adapter connected to the database while you keep it in the session, that would also use up a connection to the database, which is a resource that is even more limited. That would seriously limit the number of users that the site could handle.

Generally you should only store things in the session that actually has state, i.e. something that really has data that you need to keep. Most objects take so little time to create that there is no point in keeping them just to avoid creating them again.

Comment: Little time to create does add up as work load increases. Your 8% (of total operation cycles) spread out across multiple domains, applications and clients with different resource profiles. Its what we call a nightmarish waste from haste. It is lazy and lazy programming is bad programming. Its almost always code that will have to be modified to perform in the appropriate manner, because in a production environment this costs infrastructure resources.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure, Why Would you store it in session, But Remember Session is the most **expensive** resource in web development.

Answer (score 2):

Thats always depends on your requirement.

If the data in dataset is less and you are making call to database very frequently to get same data again and again than its better to store that in session, But if data is same for all user than you should make use of Cache because its faster than session.

But if the data is large in dataset than its better to give call to database because storing data slow down your application i.e performance may decreses badly.

**Note** : this always depends on datasize and how frequently you query data from database.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends upon your requirement what you want to do and how much the data you have.

according to me session is not a good option to store data-set because once it occupies the memory will not be available.and session has some limitations  like if your session has expired then it can throw error of null, you will need to refresh it time to time.

Much better is when you need data-set with large data to give call to database because storing data slow down your application i.e performance may decreases badly. you can use indexes option in sql server to fast return the data.